# No component factory found for SendMessageComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

i want to open the component with angular material dialog .

i write this code :

```
sendMessage(): void {

 const dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(SendMessageComponent, {
  data: {
    requestRefId: this.requestId
  },
  panelClass: 'semd_message'
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res => {
  if (res) {
    this.FetchMessage();
  }
 });
}
```

but when i want to open the dialog it show me this error :

```
No component factory found for SendMessageComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:27401)
at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:27477)
at CdkPortalOutlet.attachComponentPortal (portal.js:810)
at MatDialogContainer.attachComponentPortal (dialog.js:354)
at MatDialog._attachDialogContent (dialog.js:1161)
at MatDialog.open (dialog.js:1028)
at MessageComponent.sendMessage (message.component.ts:71)
at Object.handleEvent (message.component.html:3)
at handleEvent (core.js:45703)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:47343)
```

in my module i define a SendMessageComponent in `declarations` , `entryComponents` , `exports` .

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [ListComponent, SendMessageComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    EMoneyDepositRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule ,
    PageLayoutModule,
    SecondaryToolbarModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    BreadcrumbsModule,
    Angular2PromiseButtonModule.forRoot(promiseButtonConfig)
  ],
  exports:[SendMessageComponent],
  entryComponents: [SendMessageComponent]
})
export class EMoneyDepositModule { }
```

**now whats the problem ? how can i solve the problem ???**

Comment: is `EMoneyDepositModule` a lazy loaded module?

Comment: Try restarting your server `ng serve` or `npm start`. IT may occure when you make new files, Angular does not add them to the currently running server.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner yes its Lazyloaded

Comment: @Random i try that . its not worked

Comment: Do you maybe have another SendMessageComponent, which is imported in the module instead of your required one?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm i have SendMessage Component in other Module not this module

Comment: @kianoushdortaj Yes, but check your import statement in the ts file, does it refer to the correct SendMessageComponent? I mean the top import like `import { SendMessageComponent } from './mypath/send-message.componen't`. Is the path correct?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm yes its currect

Comment: Then I am going to provide you another possibility in answers

Comment: I know the problem, I'll post an answer soon

Answer (score 2):

If you encounter this problem, I assume you use Angular v8 or less. With Ivy, you are no longer required to add a dynamically rendered component into `entryComponents`. One option would be to upgrade your angular version.

**Why do we need to add a dynamically created component into `entryComponents`?**

When creating components, Angular needs `ComponentFactory` to resolve them. When you use your components within a template angular creates factories for those components. However, dynamically rendered components are not used in any template. That's why you need to tell Angular to create a factory for these components by adding them into `entryComponents` (With Ivy-a.k.a Angular v9+, this is no longer the case). Let's look at your case.

You have a lazy loaded module `EMoneyDepositModule` and you added `SendMessageComponent` into `entryComponents`. What this does is to create a factory for `SendMessageComponent` within sub part of injection tree. It is only available to those under `EMoneyDepositModule`. Anyone within outside of this module, cannot inject that factory. I assume `matDialog` is globally provided and you can access it anywhere. However, `matDialog` cannot access lazily loaded modules' factories.

I've been able to reproduce your problem. [Check it here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-qpwwyv?file=src%2Fapp%2Flazy-module%2Flazy.module.ts)

So you can do one of these followings

1. Add `SendMessageComponent` to the `entryComponents` of which module `matDialog` is provided.
2. Somehow provide a `matDialog` in your lazily loaded module. I assume you achieve this by simply importing `MatDialogModule` in `EMoneyDepositModule`
   In the example above, simply uncomment `MatDialogModule` in `lazy.module`

Comment: i not create a component in this module . i copy them of other module and declarethat in `EMoneyDepositModule `

Comment: Your code shows that `SendMessageComponent` is declared and put into `entryComponents` in `EMoneyDepositModule`. Just try importing `MatDialogModule` in `EMoneyDepositModule` @kianoushdortaj

Comment: @kianoushdortaj I've updated the answer with a blitz

Comment: i am using the angular 9 . i try your slution but it not worked for me

Comment: if you use angular 9 and can enable ivy, just do it. your problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I see possible reasons:

**New Component**

As per mentioned by @Random in the comments newly added components may not be correctly used by `ng serve`.

**Another SendMessageComponent**

You possibly refer to another `SendMessageComponent` in your ts-import statement.

**Circular reference**

Lazy loaded modules are proned for this behavior. Please check your `SendMessageComponent` and other related components. `SendMessageComponent` should not import any other element from the same module absolutely. Please change possible findings to a relative import.

Comment: i create a new component by name `Message Send` and i not have any componnt by this name . but still have this problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue in Angular 12.1 version with "No component factory found for". I origin thought that IVY is automatically installed with Angular 12.1, but it was not. The solution, I updated my compiler to use IVY and everything worked as expected. See this website for details on how in grade to [IVY](https://next.angular.io/guide/ivy)